# Viability of combining Client Credentials Grant and Personal Access Token

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, architecture, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

We have 4 projects.

GTAW = Laravel-based app, acts as IdP of all our other products, uses passport for oauth 2.

GTAD = Electron-based app, authenticates to GTAW. Needs data from OKRX and DTT.

OKRX = Laravel-based app, authenticates to GTAW.

DTT = Laravel-based app, authenticates to GTAW.

We have come up with the flow where:

GTAW, via client credentials grant, fetches the personal access token of a user from OKRX/DTT.

GTAW will then send this personal access token to GTAD.

GTAD will use personal access token to get data from OKRX/DTT.

What's the viability of this approach? Are there security risks?

Viability, risks, and things to look out for.

Comment: When asking a question in SO please ask a single specific programming related question  . This question here is actually a lot of questions packed in one and is more of an architecture/security related question than a programming one. There are other sites in the stack exchange network that may be more appropriate for it.